# GWcode Categories - show these three cats AND their children

Tags: filter, gwcode-categories, categories, children

I'm using [GWcode Categories](http://gwcode.com/add-ons/gwcode-categories) and I'm trying to figure out how to show, for example, 3 specific categories AND said categories children as well. I know of the show param though, it appears this needs to include the parent category IDs AND their children IDs to have both parents and children show up. Using show="1|2|3" I only get the 3 parent cats in other words.

That of course sucks because anytime a client adds a new child cat we have to update the show param IDs again.

It's almost like we are missing a `show_include_children="yes"` in the case of the show param. The next param (excl_cat_id) has something similar in fact.

I know there is the `excl_cat_id=""` along with `excl_cat_id_children="yes"` params which would work though, that would mean any time a new parent category is added I'd have to go in and excluded that one as well and it's children when added too. The opposite of show in other words though, the same issue.

I know about the cat_id param though, this is only for one category and it's children and of course is only half of what I need. I tried piping here without success.

What about using conditionals or Switchee? Something along the lines of this: `{if parent_id == "1|2|3"} my vars {/if}` this would probably work though, seems like there should be a way to do this with out having to loop through 1000 categories just to check for 3.

With all that said, am I missing something, is there not a way to show 3 categories AND their children based on the 3 parent IDs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I was just doing something with GW Categories that involved showing child categories. In the end I ditched it in favour of using the query module.

You could run a query something like

```
select * from exp_categories where parent_id='CURRENT CATEGORY ID'
```

and pass it your category IDs as required

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think of using a query as I thought this would be possible as is. I still think I want to use GW Cats but, maybe I could run a similar query to feed the show param with the parent IDs and their children too ala Stash.

Comment: Okay I was able to get the proper query and stash setup to grab the IDs to feed to show though, I'm not sure show param honors the parent child relationship. I wasn't able to get it working properly anyway so, that's my assumption at this point.

Comment: Maybe I'm hitting a parse issue here actually now that I think of it. I was able to get the query and stash:set setup correctly though, not sure I'm able to pass the piped IDs properly or not. I've tried a bunch of stuff including various stash embeds, stash embed vars, process (end,inline,start) etc. without success.

Comment: I had to pass pipe delimited lists to stash recently, had regex the list as I was using stashs match param, can you post what you have this far ?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd have bothered with Stash. Would the performance hit of doing 3 selects be *that* horrible? I'd probably modify the query to get specific columns though rather than using *

Comment: I tried putting the following query (along with the parent IDs) right into the show param though, I wasn't able to get it working either way and why I tried Stash: `SELECT cat_id from exp_categories where parent_id IN (3,4,5) AND group_id=1;` The query works fine of course elsewhere as does the Stash variable I created.